# how can I create an String array based on another String array whose elements contain textfield.text. Don't know how to filter it in the right way:(

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, reactivekit, swiftbond

I'm trying to implement searchTextfield to my project, I am using ReactiveKit/Bond. I create a function but don't know how to filter my array elements and create a new array based on searchTextfield.text text.

```
var myArray = MutableObservableArray(["Monkey", "Tiger", "Lion", "horse"])

searchTextField.reactive.text
    .ignoreNils()
    .throttle(for: 1.0)
    .observeNext(with: { (searchTextField) in
        let filtredArray = names.filter {$0.contains(searchTextField.text)} \\ Here is my mistake, don't know how to fix $0.contain
            
    })
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you include which error you got? What have you tried to fix the issue?

Comment: when I type let filtredArray = names.filter {$0. and trying to choose contain operator it says  Value of type 'OrderedCollectionChangeset<[String]>' has no member 'contains'